# How could I enable "Go To Definition" in VSCode with SSH on my Jetson Nano?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, ide

When I need to do "`Go to definiton`" on my Server by SSH on VSCode, it works, but:

When I use the same method on `Jetson Nano(arch:aarch64)`, it didn't work. The selection "`Go to definiton`" doesn't exits.

I'm sure that I have installed some necessary plugin, it just move to another platform.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated with [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 2816](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2816) (on `aarch64`), that can depend on the language plugin itself.

In your case, [VSCode Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), which, on Nano environment, uses [a LSP (Langage Server Protocol)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) quite glitchy for Python at the moment (as stated in [arduino/arduino-ide issue 206](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/206#issuecomment-803273479) for instance).

[`microsoft/vscode-python` issue 12499](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12499) mentions:

> We have released a new and more performant language server called Pylance which likely solves these issues you are reporting.  You can download [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/) from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and install it alongside the core Python extension.
> Because our team's development efforts have shifted to support the new language server, we'd encourage you to try it out.

Maybe that would help in this remote SSH usecase.

Comment: this attempt did nothing for me. tested on both vscode and vscode insiders

Comment: @GilHiram OK, I hope you will find a solution (and share it with us here)